# Why is Input.GetAxis('Mouse X') giving different values on build than editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Been stuck trying to figure this out for hours. My camera works fine in the editor (Game mode) but is far too fast in the OSX builds I'm creating. I've narrowed it down to `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`  and `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` producing different results. I don't think it's so much as the max values (I've tried clamping them) but the speed in which they ramp up and down.

Some test code, create a new scene and attach to a default cube:

```
private void LateUpdate ()
{
    transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (0, Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X"), 0));
}
```

The cube rotates when you move the mouse. It moves much faster in the build than in the editor. Any ideas?

Comment: I have basically zero knowledge of unity... but it just struck me while looking at the description of the problem that maybe the mouse on the Mac is a higher dpi resolution, so that for the same distance moved on the pad, it moves through more screen cords.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I convert the mouse movement to mouse movement per second, and apply the rotation in the fixed update.

```
var mouseVel : Vector2;

function Update () {
    mouseVel = Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y")) / Time.deltaTime;
}

function FixedUpdate () {
    transform.Rotate(0f,(mouseVel.x * Time.deltaTime),0f);
}
```

Just make sure that you divide the mouse movement by Time.deltaTime in the Update and then multiply the new mouse velocity by the Time.deltaTime in the fixedUpdate, as the Time.deltaTime in the fixedupdate is equal to the fixed time samples.
Hope this helps someone.